# Django language change on contry name

Tags: python, django, geolocation

i want to change site language on country name  i've already got country name by ip adress just want to change language of the site for diff countries   here is my code for ip and country  guessing

```
g = GeoIP()
ip = request.META.get('REMOTE_ADDR', None)
if ip:
    city = g.city(ip)
else:
    city = 'None' # default city




# if city['country_name'] == 'United Kingdom':
#     lang ='en'
```

in if section i want to change site language if country will be UK  but i have no idea how  any one help ? as i know  i should change url  to /en or something like that

Comment: Be aware that *country implies language* doesn't work in lots of cases. I live in Holland but my computer, browser, *everything*, is set up to display English. I don't want your site showing me a Dutch page. If I take my laptop to Korea or Lithuania on a business trip, and visit your site, I absolutely do not want to see it in Korean or Lithuanian. Look at the user's Accept-Language header in preference to deciding that you know better than they do what language they speak.

Comment: Furthermore a  lot of countries (Switzerland, Belgium, etc.) have multiple languages.